# Required only one dot at the end of nameserver

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

The regex below works nice except I need only one dot (.) at the end for nameserver. For example if user submit `ns1.hello.com` there will be error. Accepted format is with dot at the end like this `ns1.hello.com.` Help me please. Thank you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



function validSubdomain() {

    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.$/;



    var val = document.getElementById("nameserver").value;

    var val2 = document.getElementById("nameserver2").value;



if(val == '' && val2 == ''){

     alert("Please fill in the name server"); 

     document.forms['namaform'].elements['nameserver'].focus();

     return false; 

} 



if(val == ''){

     alert("Please fill in the name server 1"); 

     document.forms['namaform'].elements['nameserver'].focus();

     return false; 

} 

if(val2 == ''){

     alert("Please fill in the name server 2"); 

     document.forms['namaform'].elements['nameserver2'].focus();

     return false; 

} 



var parts = val.split('.');

var parts2 = val2.split('.');

if (parts.length < 3) 

{ alert('invalid nameserver format') 

document.forms['namaform'].elements['nameserver'].focus();

return false;

}

else if (parts2.length < 3) 

{ alert('invalid nameserver 2 format') 

document.forms['namaform'].elements['nameserver2'].focus();

return false;

}









if( !re.test(val)) {

    alert("invalid nameserver 1 format");

    return false;

}

else if( !re.test(val2)) {

    alert("invalid nameserver 2 format");

}

else{namaform.submit();}







}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things wrong with:

```
if(re.test(val && val2)) {  
    alert("valid format"); 
} 
if(!re.test(val && val2)) { 
    alert("invalid format"); 
}
```

First of all, have you never heard of `else`? It's there specifically so you don't have to repeat a test in the negative.

Second, you are trying to `&&` together the two string and then passing the resulting boolean to `re.test()`. Since a boolean converts to the string `"true"` or `"false"` it will never ever match.

Change to:

```
if( re.test(val) && re.test(val2)) {
    alert("valid format");
}
else {
    alert("invalid format");
}
```

Also note that your regex is wrong. It would accept `a..b` as input, which is clearly not valid. Try this instead:

```
var re = /^([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\.$/i;
```

This will broadly match most domains with unlimited number of subdomain levels, provided there's a `.` at the end.

**EDIT** to disallow `-` at the front of a section:

```
var re = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\.$/i;
```

Comment: +1 -- your answer is much more complete than mine -- but you actually manage to address everything *except* the actual question!

Comment: Forgot that dot on the end XD Fixed now, I believe.

Comment: @Kolink There is a problem, user can keyin any alphanumeric with the trailing 2 dots or more and the validation will accept `j..`, `7...`. This is wrong. I want to only accept this kind `agh51-.7ds--a.8jh-9a.` of format. I hope you understand me. Thank you.

Comment: That's strange, it shouldn't accept consecutive dots... Are you sure you put exactly what I typed?

Comment: @Kolink - Thats the problem, I don't use your regex but only if else. Sorry for wasting your time and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kolink: I found a new regex problem. Regex actually allowed dash at the front of nameserver like this `-.lol.com.` or `-lol.com.`. I need dash to be removed from the front of nameserver. Perhaps you could help me?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just saying that this:

```
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
```

needs to be this:

```
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.$/;
```

?

Comment: There is a problem, user can keyin any alphanumeric with the trailing 2 dots or more and the validation will accept `j..`, `7...`. This is wrong. I want to only accept this kind `agh51-.7ds--a.8jh-9a.` of format. I hope you understand me. Thank you.

Comment: @sg552: If you want help with your current code, you need to post it. (You can [edit your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9229873/edit).)

Comment: I appreciate your help. The problem has been solved. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a special character in a regex (also referred to as 'metacharacters') you need to escape it with a backslash. So, just before the $ in your regex, include

```
\.
```

to match the dot at the end of the string.

Comment: There is a problem, user can keyin any alphanumeric with the trailing 2 dots or more and the validation will accept `j..`, `7...`. This is wrong. I want to only accept this kind `agh51-.7ds--a.8jh-9a.` of format. I hope you understand me. Thank you.